# Закрытие дескриптора usb устройства, когда оно уже удалено из системы

Tags: c++

Я подключаюсь к usb устройству с помощью функции `HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile("\\\\.\\device_name",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);`

После чего если устройство было удалено до того как была вызвана функция CloseHandle, то при вызове CloseHandle происходит краш системы и BSOD. Пробовал отслеживать событие DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE чтобы закрывать дескриптор до того как устройство будет удалено, но похоже это сообщение не приходит есть устройство удаляется небезопасно(просто извлекая из компьютера). Не могу понять как мне безопасно закрыть дескриптор, когда устройство уже отсутсвует в системе.

Comment: Какая у вас версия системы что прям BSOD выкидывает?

Comment: Windows 10 1903